# Remotely Accessing MySQL on Mac Mini/Time Capsule

Tags: mysql, macos, remote-access, portforwarding

I'm currently trying to run an application on a server but my customer is very 'picky' about their data and wish to store the database on their own internal office server. I've installed MySQL and can get the application to run locally but for a few specific reasons the application needs to run else where.

I basically can't get access to MySQL from a different location. I think my main stumbling block is port forwarding to the correct location. MySQL is installed on a mac mini with local IP address 192.168.1.242 and the router/modem is an Apple Time Capsule. I've tried looking at tutorials but they all have options that I don't have access to. I've attached a screenshot of the options I have access to and the settings I've tried so far.

[image]
[image]

Other information possibly needed is:

- I need to connect from PHP
- I've set a user up within MySQL with a wildcard (%)
- I'm testing it using the following: command on my local machine in CMD: ***mysql -u username -h remote_ip_address -p***
- I get the following error: ***ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS' (10061)***
- Firewall is turned off completely on the Mac Mini
- There is nothing in the my.cnf file
- OS is Sierra

That's all I can think of at the moment but any advice would be greatly appreciated and any more information required can be provided.

PS. evidently I'm not very good with MAC machines/networks

Comment: Just checking that the "Remote_ip_address" that you are hitting is the external WAN address for the customer, not the internal LAN 192.168.1.242 IP. Correct? The DHCP reservation and the Port Forwarding on the Airport looks correct.

Comment: Yes that's correct, avoided certain details for safety purposes but yes I am pointing at the WAN address

Comment: Instead of relying on MySQL command to test, can you switch to netcat (`netcat -vv remote_address 3306`) or telnet (`telnet remote_address 3306`) and see if you can grab a connection. I assume you can't given the error that MySQL is given, but it's worth a troubleshooting step. With `telnet` you can type `quit` to exit if you make a successful connection and need to exit.

Comment: Also, another stupid question, are you able to make the mysql connection when you are on their LAN to 192.168.1.242?

Comment: Also also... is there any chance that their ISP might be blocking that port? I'm not sure if that's a possibility as I've never run into it, but perhaps if it's a non-business line and their ISP is a bag of garbage...

Comment: Appreciate the thoroughness, I have tested telnet but not netcat, I'll give that a go when I'm at the correct machine, I can access it locally from the same machine but I haven't tested it on their lan from a different machine, again I'll test that and let you know as soon as can

Comment: Oh good! I think that "testing locally with a different machine" might be the key to narrowing this down. If it works, then we know it's either the Airport's port forwarding or the ISP (doubtful, but who knows). If it doesn't work, then the issue is with the MySQL box itself.

Comment: Can't remote into a different machine on their LAN until tomorrow now. Will let you know as soon as I've tested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can get to the server with MySQL, try a few more things locally.  Try to connect with "mysql --protocol=tcp" to ensure you're not connecting via unix socket file.  Also, try "netstat | grep 3306" to see if mysql is listening or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, eventually managed to get on to a machine on the same LAN, bit of a nightmare, they're over 150 miles away so I'm having to remote into their machines! tested telnet from another machine on their network with no luck. Connection Refused, Unable to connect to remote host are the messages I'm getting. Not sure where to go from here unfortunately. Tested mysql on the local machine using tcp and I can get access. Netstat returned nothing, I assume that means its not listening on port 3306 anyway? help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that reads this I had a very specific issue. I installed MySQL using homebrew. Homebrew binds MySQL to 127.0.0.1 therefore will only allow connections to MySQL from the same machine no matter what you try to do. To fix it I've had to edit /usr/local/Cellar/mysql//homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist and replace --bind-address=127.0.0.1 with bind-address=*.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an internal firewall of users/IPs. Even if you can connect locally, you might not have permission remotely:

Try this as `root` user on the MySQL server (locally first!)

```
 GRANT ALL ON <db>.* TO '<user>'@'<remoteIP>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Where

`<db>` is the name of the DB

`<user>` is name under which you connect

`<remoteIP>` is your external office IP **FROM** which you are trying to connect

`<password>` should be self-explanatory!

[This will explain the options better](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)